# Is my power supply dead?

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, power, desktop-computer

I recently bought a new NZXT Phantom case and went ahead and moved all my components from the old case. It took a while to get some things in, and then to do a little bit of cable management (as much as I can with a non-modular power supply). I plug in the power cord, and I see the green LED light on the motherboard light up. So far, so good.

So I press the power button, and all that I hear is a small click from the power supply. Pressing the power button again does nothing. If I unplug the cord for about 10 seconds, plug it back in and press the power button, it will do the click again. Also, the CPU fan will turn on for a split second when the power button is pressed, but will not on subsequent presses until I unplug/plug back in for 10 seconds.

So I decided to do the paper-clip test of the power supply (where you connect the green wire and one of the black wires with a paper clip). Performing this test yields the same click result as pressing the power button, and subsequent attempts won't cause any clicking until I unplug for 10.

This is very strange because the computer was working just fine earlier that day in the old case. It was on the road for about an hour and a half and brought here where we performed the case transplant.

Is my power supply dead, or could something else be at play here? I'll be watching this page and I will gladly answer any questions that you guys have.

Comment: Did you do the paper-clip test with *all* power supply connectors disconnected?

Comment: Just tried the paperclip test with the power supply completely disconnected from everything except for the paperclip and to the wall. No difference - the exact same scenario occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I would test it with multimeter:
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/power-supply-troubleshooting-with-a-multimeter/